# Tiny MCE menuitems naming

Tags: tinymce

looking for documentation for naming of tiny mce's default menuitems.

I am trying to remove menuitems (Fonts & Fontsize) from the menubars format options.
It should work with 'removed_menuitems' (Docs: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#exampleusingremoved_menuitems)
The problem is that i cannot find any information about menuitems naming.

I expected to remove Fonts from the dropdown menu id have to 'fonts' or 'font_formats' to the removed_menuitems string parameter list, but nothing seems to work although removing e.g. Formats from the dropdown menu works by adding 'formats'... so it does work in general, i just need to find those menuitems names.

Is there documentation about menuitems naming or is it me failing googling?

Answer (score 0):

It was me failing googling...

The core menu items
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/available-menu-items/